# Write asp:table into PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: asp.net, pdf-generation, itext

I'm looking for a way to write an asp:table Object into a pdf file. The table object is generated dynamically at runtime.
What I already found out is to write the generated object into the aspx page and read out the content back into my code behind.

I hope there is any simpler solution to perform this.

Comment: How is the table object generated? using DataTable or other data source? and which language VB, C#. Instead of first generating the table object from code behind, then assigning it to the asp:Table and then again reading that asp:table from code behind, why not directly write your table object to the pdf?

Comment: How can i write the table object directly into the pdf @haraman?

Comment: The TableObject is generated from a DataTable @haraman

Comment: *How can i write...*? It depends on the library which you use to generate PDFs. One of the commonly used libraries is iTextSharp for which you may check the links given by *Chris Haas* in comment on [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30175971/exporting-datatable-to-pdf-with-columns-spanning-multiple-pages#comment48467244_30175971)

Comment: This article may also be of some help to you http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-DataSet-or-DataTable-to-Word-Excel-PDF-and-CSV-Formats.aspx